# Change Default Delay send in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want to change the default Delay Send options so that if I send on a weekend I have a quick link to delay until Monday at 6:30 or 7:00 am, and if I send during a weekday (Mon. - Thurs) in the evening I can select Delay Send and the default for the Delay Send Quick Access Toolbar is the next day around 6:30 or 7 am.

I went through all the steps to create the macro as outlined on this post:
[Outlook: Change default email delay for "Do not deliver before" feature](https://superuser.com/questions/628983/outlook-change-default-email-delay-for-do-not-deliver-before-feature)

but when I went to run the macro I received this error:

> an error has occurred on line 0, with a description: object variable or
>   with block variable not set, and an error number 91.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted essentially the same solution as you and had some trouble with that macro as well. I searched a couple other sites and eventually found [this solution](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/95100-delay-sending-an-email-until-the-next-working-day-public-holidays/) that got me most of the way there. I revised their macro a bit to end up with the code below. I only added a button to run the macro on the Quick access toolbar for New Messages and haven't tested the original code's error handling so I can't vouch for that, but left it in.

Things I changed from the original:

- Changed the comparison with the NoDeferredDelivery default time to
  be not equal since I only want to remove the delay if a delay is
  already set.
- Added an Exit Sub to that If block since otherwise it would continue on and put the delay in anyway.
- Revised the date calculation logic so that my default send time is 7:38 AM the next morning if it is Sun-Thurs, then Monday morning if it is Friday or Saturday.
- Updated the message box that tells you the new send time to include the day of the week so it would be clear if you ran it on a Friday or Saturday that it would go to Monday instead of tomorrow morning.

```
Sub DelaySendMail()
        On Error GoTo ErrHand               ' Error Handling
        Dim objMailItem As MailItem         ' Object to hold mail item
        Dim SendDate As String              ' The date to send delayed mail
        Dim SendTime As String              ' The time to send delayed mail
        Dim MailIsDelayed As Boolean        ' Set if the mail will be delayed
        Dim NoDeferredDelivery As String    ' Value if deferred delivery is disabled
        
        SendTime = " 07:38:00"              ' Time to deliver delayed mail (7:38 AM)
        MailIsDelayed = False               ' We assume it's being delivered now
        NoDeferredDelivery = "1/1/4501"     ' Magic number Outlook uses for "delay mail box isn't checked"
        
        'Set object to mail item you have open
        Set objMailItem = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        
        ' Check and make sure current item is an unsent message
        If objMailItem.Sent = True Then
            Err.Raise 9000
        End If
     
        ' If mail is currently delayed, remove the delay and quit
        If objMailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime  NoDeferredDelivery Then  'Altered since test wasn't working in original
            objMailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = NoDeferredDelivery
            MsgBox "Mail will be delivered immediately when sent", _
                    vbOKOnly, "Deferred delivery removed"
            Exit Sub 'Added since otherwise it didn't actually quit the method
        End If
            
        ' Set the date appropriately for the next weekday
        If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 5 Then
            ' Today is Friday
            ' Delay mail three days
            SendDate = Date + (3)
            MailIsDelayed = True
        ElseIf Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 6 Then
            ' Today is Saturday
            ' Delay mail two days
            SendDate = Date + (2)
            MailIsDelayed = True
        Else
        ' Today is Sunday-Thursday so delay till tomorrow morning
            SendDate = Date + (1)
            MailIsDelayed = True
        End If
        
        If MailIsDelayed Then
            ' Mail should be delayed - set the delivery date/time
            objMailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = SendDate & SendTime
            'Altered to include day it would be sent for visiblity over a weekend
            MsgBox "Mail will be delivered on " & _
                    WeekdayName(Weekday(SendDate)) & ", " & SendDate & " at" & SendTime, _
                    vbOKOnly, "Mail delayed"
        End If
    
        Exit Sub
    
    ErrHand:
        ' Handle well-known errors with message
        ' Other errors, just tell the user
        If Err.Number = 13 Then
            ' No current item or current item isn't a mail message
            MsgBox "Future delivery can only be set on mail items", vbOKOnly, "Not a mail item"
        ElseIf Err.Number = 9000 Then
            ' The active message has already been sent
            MsgBox "Please run this macro from an unsent mail item", vbOKOnly, "Not an unsent mail item"
        Else
            MsgBox "An error has occured on line " & Erl & _
                    ", with a description: " & Err.Description & _
                    ", and an error number " & Err.Number
        End If
            
    End Sub
```